# Constrained motion in a parabolic tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

> *A smooth parabolic tube is placed with vertex downwards in a vertical plane. A particle slides down the tube from rest under the influence of gravity. Prove that in any position, the reaction of the tube is equal to $$2w({h+a})/\rho$$ where $w$ is the weight of the particle, $\rho$ the radius of curvature of the tube, $4a$ the latus rectum and $h$ the initial vertical height of the particle above the vertex of the tube.*

I am not able to figure out how to  write the equations of motion for motion in a parabolic tube. Have read constrained motion for a vertical cycloid. Is a tubular cycloid and parabolic tube the same? Please help!

Comment: Sorry, what is $p$?

Comment: Oops sorry for the typo...I have corrected it now.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the [radius of the curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(mathematics)) of a parabola? I think that's the crucial part of the problem.

Comment: No sorry I don't will try to check on the net

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**  This is a through solution, I only wrote it because I thought the steps are similar in many problems. Whenever you feel you can solve the rest of the problem; ignore my solution and do the rest yourself.

The image below is showing the particle at a particular instant.

[image: parabola]

The [radius of curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_%28mathematics%29), $R$, can be calculated as:

> $$R = \left|\frac{\left( 1+y'^2\right)^{3/2}}{y''}\right| = \frac{\left( 4a^2 + x^2\right)^{3/2}}{4a^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt a}(y+a)^{3/2}$$

And the speed of the particle at a given point:

> $$v=\sqrt{2 g y}$$

The particle is moving on a parabola, writing the forces perpendicular to the surface:

> $$m g \cos{\theta}-N=m \frac{v^2}{R}$$

where,

> $$\cos \theta = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 \theta}}= \sqrt\frac{1}{1+y'^2}=\sqrt\frac{a}{a+y} = \frac{2(y+a)}{R}$$

Now calculating $N$, we get:

> $$N = 2mg\frac{y+a}{R}-2mg\frac{y}{R}=\frac{2mga}{R}$$

You can perhaps try and translate it back to the less intuitive notation given in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response....Thank you Ali I'll try that out